# How to make a project use actual months

Tags: planning, ms-project-2016

I am trying to create a project where the duration is calculated in Months. Eg. The project starts on M1 (month January), shall finish on M24 (month December next year).

Scenario 1: I'm adding a new task. Task mode: auto. Start of the project: Wed 01-01-20. Duration 1 emon. The result is Finish on Fri 31-01-20 which is correct.

Scenario 2: I'm adding a new task. Task mode: auto. Start of the project: Wed 01-01-20. Duration 16 emon. The result is Finish on Fri 25-04-21 whereas I expected 30-04-21.

What am I missing in the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

An elapsed month (emon) is always 30 elapsed days long (i.e. 30x24 = 720 ehours).  Since 12 emons = 360 days, not 365, your schedule will fall 5 days behind each year.  There is no unit of duration in MSP that aligns with calendar months.

Comment: So the only solution would be to manually insert the start and end dates..

Comment: You could just use Excel.

Comment: ... or a VBA macro to "adjust" the EOM dates that are not actual EOM. Nevertheless, I'd guess if this function isn't available in a tool such MS Project, there  may be better ways of achieving the underlying result (i.e. looking for month-based plans may not be ideal).